# How to use "echo" to redirect (or write) a echo redirection command to a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, redirect

There are more details:
In ***A.bat*** file, I want to write a statement to another ***B.bat*** file with echo redirection, but the statement is another echo redirection.

What I want to implement are following:

***A.bat :***

```
    echo echo | set /p log=1 >> C.txt >> B.bat
```

After execution of A.bat, ***B.bat*** should be

```
    echo | set /p log=1 >> C.txt
```

So can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` to escape the special characters:

```
C:\pax>echo echo ^| set /p log=1 ^>^> C.txt >> B.bat

C:\pax>type B.bat
echo | set /p log=1 >> C.txt
```

Comment: I have run into another problem, maybe you can help me again. When I call a command in a **.vbs** file like this `sh.SendKeys "echo echo ^| set /p log=1 ^>^> \\IP\c$\\output.txt >>Execute.bat{ENTER}"`, the result in **Execution.bat** is echo  set /p log=1  \\IP\c$\output.txt, the symbol "|" is replaced by " ". So do you know how to handle it?

Comment: I have solved it. Just make the special symbol "^" enclosed by "{}".

Comment: @eXist_C: ah, yes, but what if you want to execute that VBS from Powershell over an SSH session? :-)

Comment: I just want to run a **Execution.bat** in a remote machine, so **telnet** is chosen to do that in a .vbs file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters with carets

```
echo echo ^| set /p log=1 ^>^> C.txt >> B.bat
```

If you create more than one line you can redirect a complete block.

```
(
     echo echo ^| set /p log=1 ^>^> C.txt
     echo echo Line2
)  > B.bat
```